# If the Kaiju have a hive mind, why did Slattern call for assistance with sound?

Tags: pacific-rim, kaiju

The Kaiju were hypothesised to have a hive mind. It was virtually proven when two Kaiju came through the breach to find Newt after he drifted with part of a dead Kaiju's brain.

Given that, why, in the final battle of the movie, does Slattern call for assistance from Raiju using sound instead of through telepathic means?

Comment: Perhaps for emphasis?

Comment: Because "Wails Telepathically" in closed captioning is a terrible thing to add to the final battle of the movie?

Comment: It's probably the equivalent of an emoji. Contrast "*I need assistance*" with "*I need assistance* **:-O**"*